# node js - are modules shared between users?

Tags: node.js, express

Given the following module:

```
module.exports = function() {
    var env;
    var module = {};

    module.setEnv= function(myEnv) {
       env = myEnv; // env may be set to a different value per user
    }

    module.doActionWithEnv = function() {
       ...
    }
    ...

    return module;
}
```

I require the module like so:

```
var myModule = require('/myModule')();
```

Now my question is, is my module shared between 2 different users that visit the site? By that I mean, can collisions occur if one user sets the private env variable, and then the other calls some function inside the module that depends on env and thus gets the wrong result?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, if you only have one instance of your script, then yes, the two users will share the same state.

Comment: If you only create one `myModule`, then yes, it's shared among all users. Exporting a `function` does allow you to create multiple objects, but you'll need to call that function each time you want a new object (per user) – `var myModule = require('/myModule'); ... user.env = myModule();`

Comment: how can I avoid this problem then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables on your server are generally once per server process, not once per user making a request.  Some variables like the `req` and `res` objects passed to a request handler are uniquely created for each request.  Per user variables will typically need some sort of session management layer to allow the server to identify which user is making the request and to then access data stored for that specific user.  You can read [Express Sessions](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/express-sessions/) or [Node.js and Express Sessions](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions) or [Express.js Sessions – A Detailed Tutorial](http://expressjs-book.com/index.html%3Fp=128.html) for more info about using sessions in Express and there are a number of NPM modules for implementing sessions with Express though `express-session` is likely the most popular.

---

To explain about your code, in this line of your code:

```
var myModule = require('/myModule')();
```

You will get a new `myModule` for every call to that.  So, each time you call that module constructor, you get a new `myModule` object that has a new `env` inside of it.

But, if you just call that constructor once and have only one `myModule` variable in your code and multiple requests from your web server on behalf of different users are all using that same myModule variable, then they will all be sharing the same `myModule` object and thus the same `env` variable inside of it.

---

What makes your situation a bit confusing is that modules in node.js that are created when you do `require('/myModule')` are cached and shared in node.js.  So, there is only one actual `myModule.js` loaded module as far as the node.js system is concerned.  But, each time you call the module constructor, your own code creates a new object (which you also named `module` which makes things confusing).  So, if you call that constructor `5` times such as:

```
var m = require('/myModule');
var x1 = m();
var x2 = m();
var x3 = m();
var x4 = m();
var x5 = m();
```

Or even:

```
var x1 = require('/myModule')();
var x2 = require('/myModule')();
var x3 = require('/myModule')();
var x4 = require('/myModule')();
var x5 = require('/myModule')();
```

Then, you will have 5 separate objects in the variables `x1` through `x5` and each will have their own `env` variables inside.

---

But, if you just do this once:

```
var myObj = require('/myModule')();
myObj.setEnv("hello");
```

And, then multiple request handlers all refer to that `myObj` object like this:

```
app.get('/request1', function(req, res) {
    myObj.setEnv("goodbye");
}};

app.get('/request2', function(req, res) {
    myObj.setEnv("adios");
}};
```

Then, both of these request handlers will be operating on the same `myObj` object no matter what user initiates the request.

---

> How can I avoid this problem then?

If you want per-user information stored on your server, then you would typically use `sessions`.  While there are many ways to implement a session, they usually set a unique cookie for each user's browser when they first visit your site.  There is then a storage mechanism on the server that can access data that belongs to the user with that cookie value.  You don't use normal JS variables for storing each user's state.  You would typically use either an object lookup (by cookie ID) or some sort of database.

Since it looks like you are using Express, there are several NPM modules that will hook into Express and implement sessions for you.  The most popular session implementation for Express is express-sessions.